# Recovering a message encrypted using RSA, larger than modulus

Tags: encryption, cryptography

First time asking a question so please be gentle :D. The project this is relevant to uses javascript for the encryption and decrypts in python, but at its heart, the issue is language-agnostic I think.

I wrote a program where messages are sent from a client to a server using RSA encryption. I know now that I should have used RSA encryption to pass a symmetric encryption key, but given what I have now I'm wondering...

If I encrypt using RSA a message that is longer than the modulus n, is there any way to recover that message? I ask because the client is already distributed and I'm getting some messages back that I'd decrypt by hand if possible. I figured that since in the encryption I'm raising m^e (mod n), then the resulting string after decryption... m', would be equal to m mod n: m' = m (mod n), but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's the code I use on the client side for encryption. I use a 20 digit padding of random characters, hashed with SHA256.

```
   // FUNCTIONS FOR LOGIN ENCRYPTION

function encryptString(s){

    var keys = require('main_windows/keys').getKeys();

    var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(randomString(20));

    var num_string = stringToBigInt(s + hash);

    return num_string.modPow(BigInteger(keys.keyE), BigInteger(keys.keyN)).toString();
}

function stringToBigInt(s) {
    var numeric = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        c = s.charCodeAt(i);
        if (c < 10)
            c = "00" + c;
        else if (c < 100)
            c = "0" + c;
        numeric = numeric + c;
    }
    return BigInteger.parse(numeric, 10);
}

function randomString(len) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

And here's the code for decryption on the server...

```
def decrypt(string, d, n):
    de_string = pow(long(string), d, n)
    numIn = str(de_string)
    digits = int(math.log10(de_string))+1

    pad = 3
    if digits % 3 != 0:
        pad = digits % 3
    i = pad

    output = str(chr(int(numIn[0:i])))
    while i < len(numIn) - 3*64:
        output += str(chr(int(numIn[i:i+3])))
        i += 3
    return output
```

I was trying something like this to check if I could find the true message...

```
def decrypt_too_big(string, d, n):
    real_string = pow(long(string), d, n)

    attempts = 0
    result = "failed"
    while result == "failed" and attempts < 10000:
        try:
            de_string = real_string + (attempts * (n))

            numIn = str(de_string)
            digits = int(math.log10(de_string))+1

            pad = 3
            if digits % 3 != 0:
                pad = digits % 3
            i = pad

            output = str(chr(int(numIn[0:i])))
            while i < len(numIn) - 3*64:
                output += str(chr(int(numIn[i:i+3])))
                i += 3
            result = output
        except:
            pass
        attempts += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Since this is actually a cryptography question (rather than a programming question), you likely would get better response on crypto.stackexchange.com. Even though there's JavaScript, it's really off topic here.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier I'll move it there

Comment: I just thought about it a little more and realized that while m' == m (mod n), if it's even 20 characters over the limit, m * 10^(20*3) > n, so there will be a ton of possibilities to check, making it unfeasible...